# dispatch_async for IOS 7

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, swift2, dispatch-async

I am using this in my code, and it is perfectly running as i want. I've seen that is only available for ios8. I want to run it on minimum ios 7.0 or 7.1 version. Can anyone please tell me is there any method same like this for ios 7. Or anyone have any idea how i can run this for ios 7?
Thanks

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.rawValue), 0)) {
//download code here

           for _ in self.posts.valueForKey("enclosure") as! [NSString]{
                let picURL = self.posts.objectAtIndex(self.indeX).valueForKey("enclosure") as! String
                let url = NSURL(string: picURL)
                let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
                let IMG = UIImage(data: data!)
                let dtA : NSData = NSData(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(IMG!)!)

                print("download\(self.indeX)")
                self.imageArrayNsData.append(dtA)
                self.indeX++
                print(self.indeX)

            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                 // After downloading do some task
            }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What part of your code are you having trouble getting to work under iOS 7? dispatch_async most certainly does work under iOS 7.

Comment: Your code has a variety of problems. You are doing UI calls from a background thread, which is bad. The first 3 lines of your code inside the `dispatch_async()` block that start the activity indicator spinning, add a subview, and set `userInteractionEnabled = false` should all be outside the dispatch_async closure. You are also supposed to use NSURLSession rather than calling `NSData(contentsOfURL:)` from a background thread. `NSURLSession` will manage the background fetch for you.

Comment: I feel it's also worth noting that only [5% of devices are running < iOS 8](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store/), and that the release of iOS 10 is just around the corner. It's almost certainly not worth spending a non-trivial amount of time on supporting iOS 7.

Comment: Duncan C, it says `'QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED' is only available on iOS 8.0 or newer` Can you please tell me `NSURLSession` method for downloading images .Thanks

Comment: Use: `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` or `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT` instead. or else use a DispatchGroup with NSURLSession.

Comment: Thanks now it works